# spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream-1.3.0: IllegalAccessError cannot access its superinterface

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Trying with spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream 1.3.0.RELEASE version

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    
    <name>kafka-kstream-processor</name>
    <description>kafka-kstream-processor demo application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <!--<version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Log trace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaProcessorConfiguration' defined in file [/Users/barath/barath-github-projects/spring-cloud-kafka-kstream/kafka-kstream-processor/target/classes/com/barath/app/KafkaProcessorConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.annotations.KStreamProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.$Proxy93 cannot access its superinterface org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamBoundElementFactory$KStreamWrapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.barath.app.KafkaKstreamProcessorApplication.main(KafkaKstreamProcessorApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.annotations.KStreamProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.$Proxy93 cannot access its superinterface org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamBoundElementFactory$KStreamWrapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.invokeSetupMethodOnListenedChannel(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$100(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.doWith(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:141) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.$Proxy93 cannot access its superinterface org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamBoundElementFactory$KStreamWrapper
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.defineClass0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.access$300(Proxy.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:642) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:719) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:122) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:112) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:96) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamBoundElementFactory.createOutput(KStreamBoundElementFactory.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamBoundElementFactory.createOutput(KStreamBoundElementFactory.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory$2.doWith(BindableProxyFactory.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.afterPropertiesSet(BindableProxyFactory.java:134) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(KStreamProcessor.class)
public class KafkaProcessorConfiguration {


    @StreamListener(value = "input")
    @SendTo("output")
    public KStream<?, String> splitStrings(KStream<?, String> input) {
        input.print();
        System.out.println("PROCESSOR WITH INPUT "+input.toString());
        return input
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")));
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=kafka-kstream-source-output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=kafka-kstream-processor-output
```

P.S: Note same thing works with 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT as shared in this repo https://github.com/mbogoevici/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream

=================================

Update:

Removed devtools dependency as suggested.

Logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaProcessorConfiguration' defined in file [/Users/barath/barath-github-projects/spring-cloud-kafka-kstream/kafka-kstream-processor/target/classes/com/barath/app/KafkaProcessorConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamStreamListenerResultAdapter.adapt(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.barath.app.KafkaKstreamProcessorApplication.main(KafkaKstreamProcessorApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamStreamListenerResultAdapter.adapt(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.invokeSetupMethodOnListenedChannel(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$100(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.doWith(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:141) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Certainly looks like dependency version mismatch. hence sharing the dependency tree for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you are using the devtools artifact in the application? Can you remove that and try again? It seems like there might be a bug with how some of the proxying works behind the scenes. We are looking at the issue further.

You probably want to bring all your `spring cloud stream` dependencies to the `1.3.0` line.

Could you provide a simple sample application on GitHub where we can reproduce the issue?

I ran the sample app by upgrading all the scst versions to 1.3 and I am not getting the exception you are getting. Instead of using the spring-cloud BOM, try to use this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
                                <version>Ditmars.RELEASE</version>
                                <type>pom</type>
                                <scope>import</scope>
                        </dependency>

                </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: We use devtools for local development purpose. removed as suggested, now new error pops up. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Here is the link https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/kafka-kstream-processor.git. Ya trying to change the dependencies to 1.3.0